# How to disable validation when entering a value for jQuery plugin - formvalidation?

Tags: jquery, validation, formvalidation-plugin

I am using
[FormValidation](http://formvalidation.io/), a jQuery plugin to validate my form.

If I have a validation set up like this:

```
$form.formValidation({
    framework: 'bootstrap',
    excluded: ':disabled',
    message: 'This value is not valid',
    row: {
      selector: 'div'
    },
    fields: {
      'name': {
        validators: {
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'Please enter your name'
          }
        }
      }
}
```

On every input into my input field `name`, the validation triggers. I would want for the validation to trigger only when I click on `submit` button (`which I have already done in my code`), but `I am failing to disable the validation when entering a value into a input field`.

How can I do that? What settings above I need to change or add?

Comment: http://formvalidation.io/settings/#form-live

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to add a `live` property and set it as `disabled` like this:

```
$form.formValidation({
    framework: 'bootstrap',
    excluded: ':disabled',
    live: 'disabled',
    message: 'This value is not valid',
    row: {
      selector: 'div'
    },
    fields: {
      'name': {
        validators: {
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'Please enter your name'
          }
        }
      }
}
```

[Settings: Form live](http://formvalidation.io/settings/#form-live)

I have created an answer. Thanks @CBroe